# NSCachedURLResponse willCacheResponse does not get called

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

We have set up a simple NSURLConnection and NSURLCache as per the abbreviated code snippet below. We have made sure, that the server (localhost:9615) returns the following caching headers:

```
ETag : abcdefgh
Cache-Control : public, max-age=60
```

However, the willCacheResponse delegate method is never called. Any idea?

Code:

```
// In the app delegate
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];

// Triggered by a UIButton
- (IBAction)sendRequest:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"sendRequest");
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9615"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSMutableData *receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
        receivedData = nil;
    }
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    NSLog(@"willCacheResponse");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How large is the response object? If more than roughly 5% of your 20mb persistent cache (i.e. 1mb), it might not even attempt to cache.

Answer (score 11):

Cocoa applies all sorts of criteria to determine whether it can cache. For example, in my experience, you will not see `willCacheResponse` called if the size of the response exceeds roughly 5% of the persistent storage cache size. I've also seen others claim that if `max-age` is smaller than `1835400`, it won't cache either (this is not my experience, but perhaps older iOS versions suffered from this). Obviously, the request has to be a `http` or `https` request, not `ftp` or `file` request.

If my cache is large enough (and my response correctly supplies `Cache-Control` and `Content-Type`), I find that the cache works properly. I only wish that Apple would clearly articulate the criteria being applied (either in documentation or return codes) as I and others have wasted hours diagnosing cache failures only to realize that Cocoa was applying some secret rules.

Note, if `NSURLConnection` was, itself, satisfied by retrieving it from cache, `willCacheResponse` will not be called. And, of course ensure that `didFailWithError` was not called.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for taking the time. Would you mind pasting code snippets that you found working? I would then test against our servers.

Comment: @Ralf I largely used your code, so I don't know what you'd want me to share. Do I infer from this that what you're sending is considerably smaller than 1mb and that the cache size was not the problem? Also, are you sure the response wasn't already cached? Is the request a http/https request? Can you update question with full `NSURLResponse`?

Comment: " I and others have wasted hours diagnosing cache failures only to realize that Cocoa was applying some secret rules" Count me amongst the 'others' - glad I found your answer. What a monumental waste of time - thanks Apple!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate/1411612-urlsession Criteria for calling this method are documented here.